# AJAX loading content into page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to include a file on my server using AJAX, the only problem is that it stops my php code from working.

The page I'm using ajax at:

```
<div id="content">
<!--- HERE GOES CONTENT --->
</div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mywebsite.com/func/contentpage.php',
    dataType: 'html'
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Assuming the request returns HTML, replace content
    $('#midten').html(data);
});
    </script>
```

contentpage.php code:

```
<?php
$g1 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `sesid` = '" . $_SESSION["uises"] ."' AND abd='" . $_SESSION["uiabd"] ."'");
$ui2 = $g1->fetch_object();

echo $ui2->name;
?>
```

The code above should echo a name from the database but for some reason it does not.

If I use php and include the page like this: `include("/func/contentpage.php")` it echo the name without any problems.

But when trying to load the page with ajax it does not echo a name or anything. The reason I'm using AJAX is to load content when buttons is clicked without the browser having to reload.

How can I solve this problem with AJAX or another method? I could use in php to change the path in include without having to reload the webpage/load the whole website again.

Comment: You never assign `$database` in `contentpage.php`. When you load it with `include()` it uses the variable that was assigned earlier in that script.

Comment: *"but for some reason it does not"* - Then what does it do when you debug?  In your browser's debugging tools, are any errors returned from the server?  If you add specific output to that PHP code, do you see that output at all?  Is error reporting turned on?  Are there any errors or warnings in the PHP logs?  The code shown implies that `session_start()` wasn't called, and it would need to be called before reading any session values.  What is `$database`?  It's never defined in the code shown.  When you debug, what is the resulting query being executed against the database?

Comment: `contentpage.php` doesn't seem to be designed as a standalone script, since it doesn't initialize sessions, open a database connection, etc. It's meant only to be included in some other script that performs the setup first.

Comment: $database is defined at top of the page that im using ajax at, soo not in contentpage.php

Comment: @PatricNøis: Then it's not defined.  The HTTP request is being made to `https://mywebsite.com/func/contentpage.php`, that's the PHP script being executed.  Anything that script needs to know or do has to be defined or made available to it.

Comment: Please see https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Please take care with your spelling. An English spell-checker is advised. If you are posting on a mobile device and find it difficult, wait until you can use a desktop machine instead.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you can echo out anything else other than name, but if there are errors in your PHP file then there will be a message in the developer console, something like `502 internal server error`.

Your `contentpage.php` is missing a lot of declarations and references.

```
<?PHP
session_start();//since you are using sessions here
$database = something;//undefined variable
//better use a file where you have declared all the variables and 
//then include it here
require variables.php;//something like this
$g1 = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `sesid` = '" . $_SESSION["uises"] ."' AND abd='" . $_SESSION["uiabd"] ."'");
$ui2 = $g1->fetch_object();

echo $ui2->name;
?>
```

For more information on what actually going wrong, visit `https://mywebsite.com/func/contentpage.php` using URL, if you have `error_reporting()` enabled you will see the errors.

If there are no errors in `.php` then you need to check with your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the datatype HTML to text, Because return response in text not a html, because of that response is empty

Try this:

```
<div id="content">
<!--- HERE GOES CONTENT --->
</div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mywebsite.com/func/contentpage.php',
    dataType: 'text'
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Assuming the request returns HTML, replace content
    $('#midten').html(data);
});
    </script>
```